# how to evaluate or fulfill required accuracy for regression aka precision of estimation?

Tags: error, accuracy, measurement-error, error-propagation

Maybe there is already a question similar to mine but there are so many involving the term accuracy and at least none, except of [How to evaluate instrumentation accuracy?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/226678/how-to-evaluate-instrumentation-accuracy) , didn't seem "very" similar.

A simple question: The task is to measure a device and f(x) has to be determined under a given accuracy. For example, there is a voltage measurement device and you have to check if the output voltage is better than 0.1 V precise.
How to proceed that? 
Is it possible one with the help of the data points? I assume it isn't that trivial as probably several errors have to be taken into account?
EoV maybe, too?

Comment: This is very vague. Are you asking about a confidence interval?

Comment: Maybe, I forgot to ask if a confidence interval would represent an estimation accurancy? 
Means, I would need to fulfill a given confidence interval instead of performing some methods and gather which confidence intervals they do have. Is that even possible? Or do I have to trial and error and hope that the confidence interval is as required?

Comment: A confidence interval would tell you the range of possible values of your estimate. So for ex. if your estimated accuracy would be 0.5 and your 95 % CI would be [0.4,0.6], that would give you a sort of range of likely possible values.

Comment: thanks, but I won't know this before I did everything already, or?

Comment: You estimate the CI after the fact, just like any other estimate. Maybe you are looking for some sort of power analysis?